# 50000 rows update in tabulator table

Tags: tabulator

The issue i am facing is 50000 rows i am trying to update by using addData method but the screen is getting stuck and the app is unresponsive. If i use setData method i am getting an issue like scroll is not persisting. Is there a solution

The issue i am facing is 50000 rows i am trying to update by using addData method but the screen is getting stuck and the app is unresponsive. If i use setData method i am getting an issue like scroll is not persisting. Is there a solution. If i use addData method why the UI is getting stuck it should work seamlessly